# How to get all specific cryptocurrency platform contracts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, smartcontracts

Usually, we need ABI to decode the data in a transaction. Now I want to ask whether we can get all contracts of a specified cryptocurrency. For example, I have a batch of txs waiting to be decoded and they all invoked MakerDao contracts. How can I get all MakerDao ABI by one grab in the database?
Or this is how I used to get contract ABI

```
connector = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={Address}&apikey={self.Etherscan_key}"
self.Abi = basic_json.loads(requests.get(connector).text)
```

how to know which platform(E.g MakerDao, Aave or Compound, etc.) this contract belong to?

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, impossible. To do this, one would need to both be able to detect if a contract implements an ABI (not possible), *and* to enumerate all smart contracts (even less possible).

It is impossible to detect if a smart contract implements an ABI because of the fact that ABIs are actually abstractions. Ethereum itself has no idea of what a function is.

It's even less possible to enumerate all smart contracts because every address is actually a smart contract (yes, that includes your own wallet). However, even detecting non-empty addresses is extremely difficult as it would require going through the entire blockchain searching for contract deployments (which would appear as ether transfers to the zero address).